# Passing conditional param to Eager Loading in larave ends with error

Tags: php, laravel, conditional-statements, eager-loading, laravel-query-builder

my code is as followed:

```php
   return User::whereHas('roles', function ($role, $query) {
            return $role;
            $query->whereId($role);
        })->get();
```

what I am trying is to pass role id here to query builder.

it ends up with following error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\UserController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(), 1 passed in /Users/x/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php on line 962 and exactly 2 expected
```

Comment: closure directly return $role ?

Comment: testing if i get the role or not inside the builder.

Comment: I have posted my answer, you can try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

A closure is a function that is evaluated in its own environment, which has one or more bound variables that can be accessed when the function is called.

The `use()` keyword let's you **import variables from outside the function environment**, inside the function.

```php
return User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) use ($role) {
    return $query->whereId($role);
})->get();
```