# Laravel eloquent, joining tables and make filter queries

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to write queries to filtering tables, but it's looks like something is not right.

```
    $keyword = "chapel";        
    $city = $request->get("city");
    $price = $request->get("price");
```

First checking the plans table empty or not. Then start to write filtering queries.

```
    $datas = Place::whereHas("plans")
    ->groupBy("address","place_name")
    ->when($keyword, function($query, $keyword) {
        return $query->where("place_name", "LIKE", "%$keyword%");
    })
    ->when($city, function($query, $city) {
        return $query->where("city", "LIKE", "%$city%");
    })
```

The queries working till basic_info table. But when I when search `$keyword` in `basic_info` table then then error pops and says

> Call to undefined relationship [basic_infos] on model > [App\Model\Place].

```
    //basic info table
    ->when($keyword, function($query) use ($keyword){
        $query->with(["basic_infos" => function($query, $keyword){
            return $query->where("basic_info.wedding_style", "LIKE", "%$keyword%");
        }]);
    })
    //plan table
    ->when($price, function($query) use ($price){
        $query->with(["basic_infos" => function($query, $price){
            return $query->where("plans.plan_price", "<=", $price);
        }]);
    })

    ->paginate(20);
    return $datas;
```

But actually it's defined. Here is the models

**Place Model**

```
public function basicInfos()
{
    return $this->hasMany("App\Model\BasicInfo");
}
```

**BasicInfo Model**

```
public function place()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Model\Place");
}
```

But in query inside `->when` function, when I use `->with` it seems, there is a problem happening. I guess, I am using it at wrong time or else... Same thing surely will happen to `plan` table's query too.. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You need to use your function name instead of table name for relationship.
2. If you want to use another params except `$query`, use [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58929707/passing-conditional-param-to-eager-loading-in-larave-ends-with-error/58929751#58929751).

```php
->when($keyword, function($query) use ($keyword){
        $query->with(["basicInfos" => function($query) use ($keyword){
            return $query->where("wedding_style", "LIKE", "%$keyword%");
        }]);
    })
```

Comment: Oh, I get it. thank you for point those out. It helped a lot.