# How to pass parameters to a function

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatables

This is my `addColumn` function, to which I want to pass these two parameters, `$result` and `$filter_id`.

```
->addColumn('check_field', function ($result,$filter_fld) {
  $check_fields = $filter_fld;
  $check_field_arr = $this->createAarrayChackList($check_fields);
  $status = in_array($result->id, $check_field_arr)==true ? 'checked' :'';
  return '<input type="checkbox" class="chk itemName form-check-input" id="seasel" value="$data->id" name="origin_port" onclick="get_value_to_hidden_field();" '.$status.'>';
})
```

How can i pass the two parameters?

Comment: If they are variables from an outer scope that you want to pass into the functions scope, without being arguments to the function, you can use `function (..) use ($filter_fld, $result) {`

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58929707/passing-conditional-param-to-eager-loading-in-larave-ends-with-error/58929751#58929751

Answer (score 2):

You are passing parameters to a function that be named **closure**.

**A closure** is a function that is evaluated in its own environment, which has one or more bound variables that can be accessed when the function is called.

The use() keyword let's you **import variables from outside the function environment**, inside the function.

```php
->addColumn('check_field', function () use ($result, $filter_fld) {
  ...
})
```